# How to trim and merge using Fluent FFMpeg?

Tags: node.js, video, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

Here's what I want to do with fluent-ffmpeg:

I have 3 input files. An intro, main, and outro video. I wish to merge the three, while trimming the main video. Here is my code:

```
var ffmpegCommand = ffmpeg();
ffmpegCommand.addInput(introVideo);
ffmpegCommand.addInput(mainVideo).seekInput(20).duration(3);
ffmpegCommand.addInput(outroVideo);
ffmpegCommand.on('error', function(err, stdout, stderr){
  console.log("FAILED!\n\t"+err+"\n\t"+stdout+"\n\t"+stderr);
});
ffmpegCommand.on('end', function(){
  console.log('COMPLETE!');
});
ffmpegCommand.on('start', function(commandLine) {
  console.log('Spawned Ffmpeg with command: ' + commandLine);
});
ffmpegCommand.mergeToFile('final.mp4', './vid_files/tmp');
```

The program executes fine, but when I ffplay final.mp4, the result is that introVideo plays then the video appears to freeze. According to the fluent-ffmpeg documentation, it states "Each of these [Input options] methods apply on the last input added". So I can't figure out why that syntax doesn't seem to work...

How can I trim the main video to send to mergeToFile?

Note that this works fine if I don't have .seekinput(20).duration(3) on the second addInput.

Oh, here's the outputted commandLine value:

```
ffmpeg -i ./vid_files/intro.mp4 -ss 20 -i ./vid_files/main.mp4 -i ./vid_files/outro.mp4 -y -filter_complex concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 -t 3 final.mp4
```